# Run user defined function for each row matching criteria of array formula if statement

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, array-formulas

I made a custom function in Excel VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Function Units(budgetYear As Integer, birthday As Date, serviceStart As Date, serviceEnd As Date, isMarried As Boolean, isServingAbroad As Boolean) As Double

    ' in this function all dates are converted to the first day of the date's month to make calculations easier

    Dim units As Double: units = 0

    ' service end date cannot be earlier than service start
    If serviceEnd < serviceStart Then
        Units = units
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim firstMonthOfYear As Date: firstMonthOfYear = DateSerial(budgetYear, 1, 1)
    Dim lastMonthOfYear As Date: lastMonthOfYear = DateSerial(budgetYear, 12, 1)

    Dim newServiceStart As Date: newServiceStart = FirstOfTheMonth(serviceStart)
    Dim newServiceEnd As Date: newServiceEnd = FirstOfTheMonth(serviceEnd)
    Dim eighteenthBirthday As Date: eighteenthBirthday = DateSerial(year(birthday) + 18, Month(birthday), 1)

    Dim thisYearServiceStart As Date: thisYearServiceStart = WorksheetFunction.Max(newServiceStart, firstMonthOfYear)
    Dim thisYearServiceEnd As Date: thisYearServiceEnd = WorksheetFunction.Min(newServiceEnd, lastMonthOfYear)
    Dim serviceMonthsThisYear As Integer: serviceMonthsThisYear = (Month(thisYearServiceEnd) - Month(thisYearServiceStart)) + 1

    ' unit multipliers
    Dim serviceTypeMultiplier As Integer: serviceTypeMultiplier = 1
    If isServingAbroad Then serviceTypeMultiplier = 2

    ' service must fall in the budget year supplied
    If newServiceStart > lastMonthOfYear Or newServiceEnd < firstMonthOfYear Then
        Units = units
        Exit Function
    End If

    If isMarried Then
        units = serviceMonthsThisYear
    ElseIf eighteenthBirthday < thisYearServiceStart Then
        ' this person is already eighteen in the supplied year
        units = serviceMonthsThisYear * 0.5
    ElseIf eighteenthBirthday > thisYearServiceEnd Then
        ' this person is under eighteen in the supplied year
        units = serviceMonthsThisYear * 0.25
    Else
        ' this person turns eighteen during the supplied year
        Dim underEighteenMonths As Integer: underEighteenMonths = (Month(eighteenthBirthday) - Month(thisYearServiceStart))
        Dim overEighteenMonths As Integer: overEighteenMonths = serviceMonthsThisYear - underEighteenMonths
        units = (underEighteenMonths * 0.25) + (overEighteenMonths * 0.5)
    End If

    ' multiply units by servingAbroad multiplier
    units = units * serviceTypeMultiplier

    Units = units
    End Function

    Private Function FirstOfTheMonth(dateToConvert As Date) As Date
        FirstOfTheMonth = DateSerial(year(dateToConvert), Month(dateToConvert), 1)
    End Function
```

I have a lookup table (named `Table1`):

[image: lookup table]

I want to run the function above on each of the rows that match a certain criteria in the lookup table via an array formula.

I've tried this:

```
=SUM(IF(Table1[Payee]="Bill",Units(G1,"1/2/2003",Table1[Start],Table1[End],Table1[Status],Table1[Location])))
```

This just gives me `#VALUE`.

I want it to do like the `SUM` function. If I had another column in the lookup table called `value`, I could do this:

```
=SUM(IF(Table1[Payee]="Bill",Table1[value]))
```

And it would sum the `value` column **just for the rows that match the criteria ("Bill")**.

How can I get the same to work with my custom function? I would prefer not to have to modify the custom function. The array formula should run the custom function for each row that matches the criteria. Am I misunderstanding how array functions work in Excel?

**Edit:**

Just in case it makes a difference, I'm using the latest version of Excel from Office 365 on a Mac.

**Edit 2:**

Added the full code from the function. Basically the function takes the months served in the `budgetYear` and applies a weight to them. Months under eighteen get 0.25 weight, months eighteen or older get 0.5 weight, and married gets 1 weight. If `isServingAbroad` is `TRUE`, the result gets multiplied by 2.

Comment: We may need the rest of `Units` to see what you actually want to do. Note - instead of `SUM(IF...)`, `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`.

Comment: @BigBen I added the function code along with an explanation.